# Adobe AIR update 20.0 left Native Extension broken

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air

There is an an AIR app which is being maintained, and for the time being, things were alright. Up until Dec. 08 when AIR update 20.0 came in, leaving an error message

"The required native extension is missing for this application. Try re-installing or contacting the publisher for assistance".

A lot of people have been seeing same, so it must be a common problem - that AIR update broke down all native extensions, like:

https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/172434/
https://support.magplus.com/hc/communities/public/questions/207651297-Adobe-AIR-The-required-native-extension-is-missing

etc. etc.

Is there any definite fix, or all we have to do is to sit and wait for Adobe to issue a fixed version? People suggests downgrading to version 19.0 but it seems impractical for any massively used app, most users will simply give up on it rather than downgrade.

Comment: What platform is this for? Guessing app is not published with active runtimes?

Comment: Not a "bug"... On OS-X this is due to Air 20 going 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air 20 on OS-X made the jump to 64-bit (Windows 64-bit will be released next) and thus any ANEs would need to be compile for ARCH x86_64 and the Air application re-packaged and published to work on the Air 20 runtime.

If you need both runtimes you can install Air 19, rename name the installer to something else, i.e. "Adobe AIR Application Installer 19.app" and then install Air 20...

> AIR 64-bit on Mac OS X
>
> The AIR shared runtime and SDK are now fully 64-bit on OSX!
>   With AIR 20, all Mac AIR applications will be 64-bit compatible.
>   If you require 32-bit compatibility for OSX, please continue to use AIR 19 to create captive runtime applications.

Re: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2051806

Comment: Great! Captive runtime seems to be the way to go! Thanks!

Comment: Yep, if your app uses 32-bit ANEs then captive runtime bundling is the way to go....